# Fetch the first item's value of the list | oData v4, SapUi5 or OpenUi5

Tags: odata, sapui5

Current Ui5 Version used 1.46.12

Using: sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel

What is Required?

Is to Fetch the first item's value "EventDate" of the list array which is received from the oData(v4) response.

View Code

```
<layout:VerticalLayout binding="{/Logs}">
    <Text text="Latest update"/>
    <Text id="LastUpdatedSynchronizeDateStringText"
          text="{EventDate}"/>
</layout>
```

Batch request response (oData v4)

```
{
 "@odata.context":"http://localhost/odata/$metadata#Logs","value":[
    {
      "LogId":12512,"ErrText":"end","EventDate":"2017-05-11T07:10:44Z","Location":"OEN","Result":0
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried & Failed:

```
<Text id="Last..." text="{EventDate}"/>
<Text id="Last..." text="{0/EventDate}"/>
<Text id="Last..." text="{0.EventDate}"/>
```

Error message is "Failed to drill down"

Answer (score 0):

Setting "**binding**" property to the collection path makes no sense, bacause it will set the binding context to the VerticalLayout control that you cannot access due to array (collection) nature. If it was the direct link to a specific object (with its keys), then it would work.

In your case, you can perform the request to '/Logs' collection via coding and in "success" method of "read" function bind the VerticalLayout to the retrieved object, then the 'text="{EventData}"' will work.

Rough steps:

1. odatamodel.read
2. handle success method
3. via odatamodel.**createKey** method construct the key to the first object
4. call "verticalLayout.**bindObject**" passing the constructed key before
5. the Text control will automatically get an update due to context change of the parent control and you will see your date

Comment: I am using oData v4 api, so cannot use the read and create calls as they are for odata v2. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/54e0ddf695af4a6c978472cecb01c64d